# Error libncurses.so.6 when using Bref Lambda custom runtime with AWS CDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bref

I am trying to use Bref custom runtime in AWS Lambda using AWS CDK instead of Serverless.

The CDK code is like below.

```js
const region = cdk.Stack.of(this).region;
    //arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:209497400698:layer:php-74:18
    const brefLayerVersion = `arn:aws:lambda:${region}:209497400698:layer:php-80:8`;
    const assetPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../lambda');
    const asset = lambda.Code.fromAsset(assetPath);
    
    const lambdaFunc = new lambda.Function(this, 'LambdaFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PROVIDED,
      handler: 'src/index.php',
      layers: [
        lambda.LayerVersion.fromLayerVersionArn(this, 'BrefPHPLayer', brefLayerVersion),
      ],
      code: asset,
    });
    
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'LambdaFunctionArn', { value: lambdaFunc.functionArn });
```

Here's the full source code https://github.com/petrabarus/cdk-bref-function

When I tried manually invoking using AWS CLI `aws lambda invoke --function-name arn:blabla`, it shows error.

The Cloudwatch Log shows something like this.

```
/opt/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I compare the deployment with Serverless Framework, the configuration (layer, code, etc) is pretty much the same. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Bref 1.0 needs provided Amazon Linux 2 Runtime. Here's the updated CDK code.

```js
    const lambdaFunc = new lambda.Function(this, 'LambdaFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PROVIDED_AL2,
      handler: 'src/index.php',
      layers: [
        lambda.LayerVersion.fromLayerVersionArn(this, 'BrefPHPLayer', brefLayerVersion),
      ],
      code: asset,
    });
```